# Why is my search() unable to find special characters?

Tags: javascript, php, string, encoding, utf-8

I think this is a character encoding problem.  My javascript search fails to identify a string whenever the string contains certain special characters such as ()* parenthesis, asterisks, and numerals.

The javascript is fairly simple.  I search a string (str) for the value (val):

```
n = str.search(val);
```

The string I search was written to a txt file using PHP...

```
$scomment = $_POST['order'];
$data = stripslashes("$scomment\n");
$fh = fopen("comments.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
```

...then retrieved with PHP...

```
$search = $_GET["name"];
$comments = file_get_contents('comments.txt');
$array = explode("~",$comments);
foreach($array as $item){if(strstr($item, $search)){
echo $item;  } }
```

...and put into my HTML using AJAX...

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","focus.php?name="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

My HTML is encoded as UTF-8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The problem is that the when I search() for strings, special characters are not recognized.

I didn't really see an option to encode the PHP created text, so I assumed it was UTF-8 too.  Is that assumption incorrect?

If this is an encoding problem, how do I change the encoding of the txt file written with PHP?  If it is caused by the above code, where is the problem?

Comment: What is the $scomment value? What is actually being written to the text file?

Comment: Strings of text.  Sentences.  Some contain special characters like parenthesis, and these are the ones not recognized.

Comment: These are normal characters and should be searchable. There is something else that is going on in your code that is preventing the desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `search()` function takes a regex.  If a string is given, it is converted into one.  Because of this, any special characters have special meanings, and it will not work as expected. You need to escape special characters.

> **Syntax**
>
> str.[search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)(regexp)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> regexp
>
> A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

If you want to search for text, use `str.indexOf()` instead, unless you NEED a regex.  If so, see here on how to escape the string: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Comment: When you say I "need to escape special characters" does that mean there is no solution to find these characters?  I just cannot have them in my search?

Answer (score 0):

Include this function in your code:

```
function isValid(str){
 return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

Hope it helps